# Recibo de Notificación de Pago

Tags: api, mercadopago

estoy implementando un Checkout básico con mercadopago, la implementación del mismo no es distinta de la ya descrita en la documentacion.

```
    MP mp = new MP("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET");
    mp.sandboxMode(true);
    String preferenceData = "..."; //Un Json como lo indica la documentacion

    JSONObject preference = mp.createPreference(preferenceData);

    String sandboxInitPoint = preference.getJSONObject("response").getString("sandbox_init_point");
```

Cabe destacar que esta activado el sanboxMode para casos de pruebas, y los pagos se están realizando satisfactoriamente con las tarjetas de crédito descritas por mercadopago.

Sin embargo a la hora de recibir la notificación no puedo implementar la lógica que describe la documentación, ya que los json que recibo no concuerdan para que la lógica del algoritmo tenga sentido. [Documentacion](https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-notifications/)

Mercadopago solo me envia estos dos Json para notificar el estado de la transacción:

1. Cuando esta en proceso la transacción

   ```
   {"topic"=>"merchant_order", "resource"=>"https://api.mercadolibre.com/merchant_orders/715722301"}
   ```

   2. Cuando termina la transacción

      ```
        {"data"=>{"id"=>"13567684"}, "date_created"=>"2018-04-24T10:17:50.000- 
        04:00", "type"=>"payment", "api_version"=>"v1", "id"=>277304461, 
        "action"=>"payment.created", "user_id"=>316441868, "live_mode"=>false}
      ```

Deberia llegar un Json con un atributo **"topic"** con valor **"payment"**, ahora en su defecto llega otro con un atributo **"type"** igual a **"payment"**, suponiendo que es así ninguno de los ID ("id"=>"13567684" y "id"=>277304461 ) que llegan pertenecen a un **payment** o a un **merchant_order**, ¿Como el Json 2 me puede ayudar a ver el estado final de mi transacción ? No existe documentación asociada a los parámetros que esperarías recibir de la notificación y siendo los que recibo en el json 2 ¿que debo hacer con ellos?

**ANEXO**
  Implemente un servicio para que se notificara por parte de mercadopago el estado de la transacción, intentando seguir la misma lógica sugerida, en general es el siguiente:

```
 app.post '/mercadopago/notificacion/:token'  do
    requestusers = params.select { |key, val| not val.empty? }.values
    msg={}
    @token = params[:token] 
    if requestusers[0] == 'payment'
      responsePayment = SDKMercadoPago.payments(requestusers[1]) #Responde que el id del payment no se encontro
      #responseMerchant = SDKMercadoPago.merchantOrder(requestusers[1]) #como el id del payment no se encuentra no puede ejecutar esta sentencia
    else
      responseMerchant = SDKMercadoPago.merchantOrder(requestusers[1])
    end
 end
```

Comment: No conozco mercadopago, pero discrepo con lo de _Deberia llegar un Json con un atributo "topic" con valor "payment"_ según la documentación que has adjuntado, el topic llega por GET así como otras variables.

Comment: @track3r Tienes razón, y lo asumí por el formato en el que llega el primer Json , cambiare el servicio para que sea llamado por Get y veré que recibe, si siguiera recibiendo lo mismo antes descritos en el Json 2 seguiria con la duda de que hacer con ellos, muchas Gracias!

Comment: Nos comentas y seguimos

Comment: Mercadopago no llama al servicio por GET, después de hacer varias pruebas solo hace la llamada por POST con los valores antes descritos. Gracias por la observación tienes razón, seguiré viendo

Comment: Puedes hacer un bucle por cada $_REQUEST a ver qué hay, aunque imagino que los de mercadopago harán como muchos otros y tendrán una url ok y otra ko, por lo que si llega a ok es que todo está correcto. Pero ya te digo que esto ocurre con las pasarelas de bancos normales, no se como funciona realmente mercadopago ni qué es exactamente.

Comment: @track3r Ya logre solventarlo, el personal de soporte de mercadopago ya no sugieren realizar test con sandboxmode, lo que me llevo a cambiar la url sandbox_init_point a init_point para realizar test y funciono perfecto. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para efectuar TEST se esta utilizando la url de **sandbox_init_point** descrita en el código:

```
String sandboxInitPoint = preference.getJSONObject("response").getString("sandbox_init_point");
```

La recomendación esta en utilizar no esta sino la **init_point** , la cual enviara un código valido de payment al servicio de notificación que configures, el id de dicho pago viene dado dentro del segundo Json de la pregunta como:

```
"data"=>{"id"=>"13567684"}
```

el cual usándolo para llamar al método **mp.get("/v1/payments" + id)** arrojara lo necesario para validar el pago.

Comment: Gracias, la verdad la documentacion de mercadopago es una porqueria y esto me esta ayudando.